# file uploading in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey there, I'm using the tutorial at http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/uploading_files_and_images_with_cakephp to try to get myself up and running with the ability to upload images.

Now, I'm very new, and really haven't a clue so this is probably the most stupid question in the world but I don't know whats going on.

Basically I follow the tutorial as best I can but when I load the page which is supposed to have the input for the image I get the rest of the form but then get 2 errors:
Method FormHelper::labelTag does not exist 
and
Method HtmlHelper::file does not exist

I've searched but only got more confused. There is something I'm meant to include that i've missed isn't there?

confused...

Comment: You need to post you view code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you've put the `uploadFiles` function in to your `APP/app_controller.php`

You would do something like this in your `add` action, for instance:

```
$fileData = $this->uploadFiles('img/uploads', $this->data['File']);
print_r($fileData);
```

What version of Cake are you using? That tutorial is quite old, and whilst the upload functionality still works fine, the `labelTag` and `File` methods are now deprecated (as of 1.3 I think). you should use:

```
echo $this->Form->label('image', 'Image');
echo $this->Form->file('File.image');
```

instead, and you should be good to go.

**edit**
You can also just use 
`echo $this->Form->input('File.range_image', array('type'=>'file'));`

as if I recall, that's the preferred way ~

Comment: You are brilliant. And you're my new best friend. Ta :)